# How to make oracle installation case sensitive?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, case-sensitive

I have oracle express installation, and by default it is case insensitive ( table creation/ keys name ). I want to change it to case sensitive. Is there a configuration to do so?

Comment: Why do you want to? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no setting, no.

In any version of Oracle, however, you can use case-sensitive identifiers by enclosing them in double-quotes.

```
create table "CamelCase" (
  "ColumnName1" integer
);
```

will create a table `CamelCase` which is case-sensitive and a column `ColumnName1` that is case sensitive.  In order to use the column, though, every reference will need to be surrounded in double-quotes

```
SELECT "ColumnName1"
  FROM "CamelCase"
```

would work.  However

```
SELECT ColumnName1
  FROM CamelCase
```

would not.

Using case-sensitive identifiers is generally a really bad idea so I would strongly suggest that you don't do so.  It is an option though.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no configuration for that. You can't make identifiers case-sensitive without [quoting them](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129), but Oracle recommends against using quoted identifiers:.

> Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers for database object names. These quoted identifiers are accepted by SQL*Plus, but they may not be valid when using other tools that manage database objects.

And even then if you have a quoted identifier that is all-caps anyway, e.g. "MY_TABLE", that is treated the same as an unquoted identifier so you can still refer to it as `my_table`, which might not be case-sensitive enough for you. Anything mixed-case or with invalid characters always has to be referred to quoted though, e.g. `select * from "My Table", which makes code harder to read and maintain (in my opinion anyway).

I'd really recommend not doing this. Anyone having to maintain your schema or code will not thank you for it.